# No sé cómo imprimir los nombres en una función C

Tags: c

Tengo que desplegar los resultados de una carrera, pero no sé dónde está mi error que no puedo mostrar los nombres del ganador:

```
do { // Animación
    for(j = 0; j <= 8; j++)
    {
        printf("|");
        for(l = 0; l <= km; l++)
        {
            printf("%c",pista);
        }
        printf("|\n");

        if(j != 8)
        {
            if(j < 4)
            {
                cont=rand() % 2;
                numero[j] += cont;
                for(k = 0; k <= numero[j]; k++)
                {
                    printf(" ");
                }
                printf("%c\n",corredores[j]);
            }
        }
        if(numero[j] >= km)
            km = 0;
    }
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
} while (km != 0);

for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
{
    if(numero[j] > compganador)
    {
        compganador = numero[j];
        ganador = (kms - numero[j]) + 10;
        numganador = j;
    }
}
system("cls");
printf("\t\t ***EL ABSOLUTO GANADOR ES: ***\n");
printf("CON %d MINUTOS...",ganador);
puts(finalistas[numganador]);
```

Comment: Que error tienes? Agrega todo tu código!

Answer (score 2):

Revisando tu código, `numganador` puede tener un valor de 0 a 4.
Así que defines tu array con 5 posibles finalistas:

```
char finalistas[][20] = {"Shalom", "Mark", "Anca", "Laurent", "Doru"};
```

No debes tener problema al imprimir tu resultado:

```
printf("\t\t ***EL ABSOLUTO GANADOR ES: ***\n");
printf("CON %d MINUTOS...",ganador);
puts(finalistas[numganador]); //puts() necesita #include<stdio.h>
```